# Options inside <select> won't align right or respond to direction RTL on IOS

Tags: css, ios, select

[This is my select element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEFvN.jpg)

I want the options inside it to be right to left, I've tried numerous solutions and can't seem to make it work.

Tried adding lots of css tags like:

`.select select option { direction: rtl; text-align: right; }`

and more..

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `direction: rtl;` to the main select element not the option element.

Comment: tried, doesn't work..

Comment: @gevergever can you share the full code or a demo so I can detect the problem

Comment: I'm arabian so I've worked with rtl text before

Comment: this is the html:
```html
<select id="check" class="selectDropDown" dir="rtl">
                        <option>בדיקה</option>
                    </select>
    </div>```

and this is the css:

```css

.selectDropDown {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;  /*For Chrome*/
  -moz-appearance: none;/*For Mozilla*/
   appearance: none;
   direction: rtl;
  font-family: "Rubik";
  font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 44px;
}```

Comment: @gevergever It looks good, if you mean that you want the circle to be on the left and the text on the right, it's not possible, and if it's not what you want and the text is not aligned rtl than the problem is that css doesn't support that for hebrew language, kindly check my answer